# Save created image to file system python and pygame

Tags: python, image, pygame

I am developing some software in `pygame` that allows a user to draw things on a canvas using different colors, pen sizes, etc. The problem is I don't know how to save the thing they have drawn as an image (e.g. png).

I need a way to frame the area where the image is on the screen and save it to the device's file system. Does anyone know how I can do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The PyGame display (window) is associated to a [pygame.Surface](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) object. Use [`pygame.image.save()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/image.html#pygame.image.save) to store the content of a *Surface* (or the screen) to a bitmap. The file type is automatically determined by the file extension:

```py
pygame.image.save(screen, "my_file.png")
```

If you just want to save a section of the screen, you can define a subsurface that is directly linked to the source surface with the method [`subsurface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.subsurface):

> `subsurface(Rect) -> Surface`
>
> Returns a new Surface that shares its pixels with its new parent. The new Surface is considered a child of the original. Modifications to either Surface pixels will effect each other.

Create a sub-surface and save it to a file:

```py
rect_area = pygame.Rect(x, y, width, height)
area_surf = screen.subsurface(rect_area)
pygame.image.save(area_surf, "my-file.png")
```

Comment: Brilliant, thanks for the help, now to add an undo option (I can't wait)