# Image not moving pygame

Tags: python, pygame

When I try to fire my knife in my game, it doesn't work. I am not very experienced in pygame. This is my first game that I'm making. It worked the first time, but now I try to call a new knife in a function and it doesn't work. I have tried a lot but it won't work. Here's my is my code:

```
# first I do this
realknifeImg = pygame.image.load('realknife.png')
Realknife_state = "ready"

# then this 
def fire_realknife(x, y):
    global Realknife_state
    Realknife_state = "fire"
    screen.blit(realknifeImg, (x, y))  

# and finally this
def outro():

    RealknifeX = 750
    RealknifeY = 400
    fire_realknife(RealknifeX, RealknifeY)

    if Realknife_state == "fire":
        fire_realknife(RealknifeX, RealknifeY)
        RealknifeX += 1
```

Comment: Shouldn't you use a loop somewhere to make your knife move?

Comment: this is at the top of my outro ending = True, and i have and while ending loop in this outro but i have tried that already. And it still doesnt work

Answer (score 1):

The position of the knife is continuously initialized in the `outro`. Set to position before the function and use the [`global` statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html?highlight=global#grammar-token-global-stmt) to change the position in the function:

```py
RealknifeX = 750
RealknifeY = 400

def outro():
    global RealknifeX, RealknifeY

    fire_realknife(RealknifeX, RealknifeY)
    if Realknife_state == "fire":
        RealknifeX += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a rect for this. It is the standard way of moving
images in pygame.

Instead of having all these variables you can just say:

```
r_knife_rect = realKnifeImg.get_rect()
r_knife_rect.x = 750
r_knife_rect.y = 400
```

Then whenever you want to move it call:

```
r_knife_rect.x += 1
```

Pygame wont like you using a tuple of (x,y) in your blit, it likes
rect style objects instead. To blit just say:

```
screen.blit(realKnifeImg, real_knife_rect)
```

Edit:
Using this also means your knife has a premade hitbox.

Comment: Using rects is a more simple solution in this case would you not say?

Comment: Oh hey, you answered one of my questions a while ago, funny coincidence https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68804453/save-created-image-to-file-system-python-and-pygame

Comment: Your answer is nice. Just wanted to note that the recommended way to draw and move images around in pygame is [`pygame.sprite.Sprite`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite).